# Failed to write flowfile to stdin due to the pipe has been ended

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-nifi, flowfile

[image]

I have been trying to get an excel file and process it using a python script in executestreamcommand. but it is showing this error.

Any idea on how to read excel file to stdin?

[image: ExecuteStreamCommand Configuration]

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

df = pd.read_excel(sys.stdin)
df.to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: `stdin` is an input stream.  You can read from it.  You should always expect a write to stdin to fail.

Comment: That is a terrible error message.  I believe it means that the pipe has been closed, almost certainly because the process that is reading from it has terminated.  It sounds like your python script is terminating prematurely.

Comment: Share your ExecuteStreamCommand config and script?

Comment: How you have configured `ExecuteStreamCommand ` processor, can you please add it to the question!

Comment: To read flowfile content, you can use something like - 
`wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=sys.stdin.read(),logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(wb, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8',engine='xlrd')


#flowfile_content = ExcelFile(BytesIO(sys.stdin.read()))
#excel_file_df = pd.read_excel(flowfile_content, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I've added some changes